# Creating a program that tests for palindrome without building the reversal (Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Java program for my AP Computer Science class that asks the user for a string and tests whether or not the string is a palindrome or not. The teacher specifically told us to not do the project by building the reversal of the string and testing it to see if it matches. I know how to do it while building the reversal but I can't think of another way to do it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class mondayassignment 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a String: ");
        String s = scan.nextLine();

                while(s.indexOf(" ") >= 0)
                       {
                            s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")) + 
s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1); 
                       }
                System.out.println("Spaces Removed:");
        System.out.println(s);
                String reverse=""; 
        for(int pos = 0; pos < s.length(); pos++)
                       {
                            reverse =  s.substring(pos, pos + 1) + reverse ; 
                       }
                System.out.println("Reverse Of The String You Inputed Is:" );
                System.out.println(reverse); 
                System.out.println("Testing For Palindrome:");

                if (reverse.equals(s))
                       {
                            System.out.println(s + " " + "is a palindrome" );
                       }
                else   {
                            System.out.println(s + " " + "is not a palindrome" );
                       }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me create a code that does it without building the reversal of the string? Many solutions I've found online uses boolean and char but the thing is, is that I haven't learn those yet. I've only learned double int and string. SO would there be a way without using boolean and char? I don't think my teacher wants us using boolean and char either because we have never discussed them.

Comment: If you haven't learned something yet, maybe now is the time to start. `boolean` and `char` aren't complicated, they're quite simple primitive types and they are the right tools for the task you have been given. A `boolean` is a simple `true` or `false` type; it can be used in `if` statements and such like. A `char` is a single character (in UTF-16); it is an unsigned 16 bit integer type according to the JLS.

Comment: yea but is there a way to solve my problem without using boolean and char?

Comment: By reversing the string, which you've said you're not allowed to do. I can't think of any other simple way to do this. Just use boolean and char; if you're learning Java, you're going to have to know how sooner or later, and they're really not complicated types.

Answer (score 1):

When you visually confirm whether a word is a palindrome or not, usually you would just check the characters from either end and start moving inwards.

So really that's two steps:

1. Check the end bits of the char if they're the same. If they aren't, it's not a palindrome, otherwise, next step
2. Move inwards from both ends, and repeat #1 till there are 1 or 0 characters left to be checked. (Hint: If you can't use chars, maybe try using a single character string :) )

Answer (score 0):

Compare the string char starting from head and tail. If all the letters are equal till the middle of the string it's palindrome.

```
boolean palindrome(string str){
  for(int i = 0 ; i < str.lenght()/2 ; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(str.lenght() - i )
       return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: While your code is probably correct (apart from String being upper cased), for obvious homework questions it's considered good etiquette to provide hints, not a working solution

Comment: You are right my bad. I will consider this next time @SeanPatrickFloyd

Answer (score 0):

```
package paintadvance;

import java.util.Scanner;

class  Palindrome_without_reverse{


public static void main(String[] ishan_vimukthi_is_my_name) {

    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    String string="";


    /*while loop to keep running the programme unlit user need it to end*/
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter string for palindrome check");
        string=scan.nextLine();

        /*this is for exiting the programme. If needed for user just type 
         "exit".It's not casesensitive that means "EXIT" is also ok.*/      

        if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {System.out.println("Programme closed"); System.exit(0); }


       /*get the length of string to a int variable */
       int length=string.length();

        /*get mid point of string in eg:- "aasaa" midpoint is letter "s" that means 2 when count from 0 .
        We can get it from dividing string length from 2.Because we use int we will get 2 as the answer. */  
        int midpoint=length/2;
        boolean ispalindrome=true;
        String x="";
        String y="";

        /*check length is odd or even eg:- "aasaa" is odd "aassaa" is even*/
        if (length%2==1) {

        /*if you want to see the method. uncomment this and understand it.     
             System.out.println("odd string");   
       System.out.println(string.substring(midpoint,string.length())+" X part");
        System.out.println(string.substring(0, midpoint+1)+" Y part");*/

       x =string.substring(midpoint,string.length());
       y=string.substring(0, midpoint+1);

        }else{
             /*if you want to see the method. uncomment this and understand it. 
           System.out.println("even string");
       System.out.println(string.substring(midpoint,string.length())+" X part");
        System.out.println(string.substring(0, midpoint)+" Y part");*/

         x=string.substring(midpoint,string.length());
         y=string.substring(0, midpoint);
        }



        int ylength=y.length()-1;
        int ylength_end=y.length();


        aa: for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {

            /* by this code we compare each 
            string part of both x and y strings 
            in eg:- aasaa   x=saa y=aas     

            we compair  0,1 of x and 2,3 of y
            and keep going.this is not a reversal but this is comparing x and y parts
            if its not equal we assign ispalindrome false if its equal it will be in true state
            */

            if (      !(x.substring(i, i+1).equals(  y.substring(ylength--, ylength_end--)))) {
               ispalindrome=false;  
            }

        }


        /* after for loop  We check string is a palindrome or not */
        if (ispalindrome) {    System.out.println("This is a palindrome");}else{ System.out.println("Not a palindrome");}        


        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: ya im still new to the community but i think this a littbit good answer !